# Simple NHibernate Query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, nhibernate

I'm looking for a way to do a simple

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = x
```

in NHibernate. I'm also not sure as whether this would be best achieved using Linq2NHibernate, or just NHibernate. Searching and reading Google's results for whatever reason hasn't given me much luck.

I'm also using MySQL as the database engine, in case there are sudden differences from SQL to MySQL in terms of syntax.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

1. Already got a SessionFactory Open
2. You Got a Session from that SessionFactory
3. You are using generics and you want to return objects of type Foo

`var fooList = session.CreateQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo =:x")

   .SetParameter("x","value of x")

  .List<Foo>();`

**Notice that:**

- x is a placeholder where its value needs to be set using setParamter(placeholder, value)